# I found this piece in a yard sale grab bag. What other elements do I need to make it work?

Tags: piece-usage

I found this piece in a yard sale grab bag. What element(s) do I need to make this element function as it was originally intended?

[image: Grab bag piece]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Technic Turntable Large Type 1 Base (2856)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=2856).

It's a [Turntable Large Type 1 Top (2855)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=2855) which is part of [Technic Turntable Large Type 1, Complete Assembly (2856c01)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=2856c01).